# Getting the name of the parent category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have child categories (cities) which belongs to parent categories (countries). I get a list of categories (cities-countries) as below:

```
  $categor = $wpdb->get_results("select * from $wpdb->terms c,$wpdb->term_taxonomy tt  where tt.term_id=c.term_id and tt.taxonomy='hotelcategory' and c.name != 'Uncategorized' and c.name != 'Blog' $substr order by c.name");

for($i=0;$i<count($categor);$i++)
    {
 echo '"'.$categor[$i]->name.' - '.$categor[$i]->parent.'",';
    }
```

I use the retrieved data in jquery autocomplete, and i can get the parent category id but not the name.

The problem is for example there are many cities named "Paris", so when i type in paris, i get like 8-9 cities with same name.(Picture1)
What i'd like to do is to have their parent category names beside the category.(Picture2)
http://s7.postimage.org/k85dhd4sr/catn.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have the ID of the parent-term, so if you want the actual name of the term you have to fetch it. One way to do that is to simply join the term table again for the `parent` ID:

```
$categor = $wpdb->get_results( "select c.*,tt.*,pc.name as parent_name 
    from $wpdb->terms c,$wpdb->term_taxonomy tt,$wpdb->terms pc
    where
        tt.term_id=c.term_id and tt.parent=pc.term_id 
        and tt.taxonomy='hotelcategory' and c.name != 'Uncategorized' 
        and c.name != 'Blog' $substr order by c.name");

// I have optimized the loop a bit. If you really need the index you can leave
// it as it is. If you don't need the index I suggest you change that to a
// foreach loop
for($i=0,$n=count($categor);$i<$n;$i++)
{
    echo '"'.$categor[$i]->name.' - '.$categor[$i]->parent_name.'",<br />';
}
```

An alternative solution without any SQL could look like that:

```
$excludes = array();

// build the "exclude" array. This step is necessary because
// get_terms expects the ID's of the terms to be excluded
foreach(array('Uncategorized', 'Blog') as $termName) {
    $term = get_term_by('name', $termName, 'hotelcategory');
    if($term) {
        $excludes[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}

$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'exclude' => $excludes,
    'name__like' => 'Paris', // replace this with your search term here
);

$categor = get_terms('hotelcategory', $args);

foreach($categor as $cat)
{
    // look up the parent
    $parent = get_term_by('id', $cat->parent, $cat->taxonomy);
    echo '"'.$cat->name.' - '.($parent ? $parent->name : '-').'",<br />';
}
```

This solution is admittedly a bit more verbose, but you don't have to worry with SQL or the database layout.

Comment: Cool, it works thanks. i just went on with the first solution.